# In OpenCV I've got a mask of an area of a frame. How would I then insert another image into that location on the original frame?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm brand new to OpenCV and I can't seem to find a way to do this (It probably has to do with me not knowing any of the specific lingo).

I'm looping through the frames of a video and pulling out a mask from the video where it is green-screened using inRange. I'm looking for a way to then insert an image into that location on the original frame. The code i'm using to pull the frames/mask is below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mov')
image = cv2.imread('photo.jpg')


# green digitally added not much variance
lower = np.array([0, 250, 0])
upper = np.array([10, 260, 10])

while(True):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

  # get mask of green area
  mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower, upper)
  cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, can you upload a video sample and the photograph as well.

Comment: c++ syntax has mat.copyTo(destination, mask) probably python syntax has something similar. But both images must be same size

Answer (score 0):

Use Bitwise operations for masking and related binary operations. Please check below code to see how Bitwise operations are done.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../video.mp4')
image = cv2.imread('photo.jpg')


# green digitally added not much variance
lower = np.array([0, 250, 0])
upper = np.array([10, 260, 10])

while(True):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

  # get mask of green area
  mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower, upper)
  notMask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
  imagePart=cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
  videoPart=cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = notMask)
  output = cv2.bitwise_or(imagePart, videoPart)
  cv2.imshow('output', output)

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**RGB bad color space**

Since, you are doing color processing, I would suggest you to use appropriate color space. HSV would be a good start for you. For finding good range of HSV values, try this [script](https://github.com/saurabheights/ImageProcessingExperimentScripts/blob/master/AnalyzeHSV/hsvThresholder.py).

**Generating Video Output**
You need a to create a video writer and once all image processing is done, write the processed frame to a new video. I am pretty sure, you cannot read and write to same video file.

Further see official docs [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).

It has both examples of how to read and write video.