# Copying a non rectangular ROI from an image and use the ROI in other image in same points

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to crop a non rectangular ROI from an image and use that ROI in the other image.

Case: I am using perspective transformation to an image and writing it in the file. And now I want to copy the certain non rectangular ROI of transformed image and paste it on the other image with same ROI. As of now both the images are of similar sizes.

Images are manually updated.

[image: <code>[![Expected output][1]][1]</code>]

[image: Perspective image]

Comment: Use binary masks, see relevant answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40047718/1874627